# Calculate Radians In Order To Have Player Face Unit - From Player(X,Y) to Unit(X,Y)

Tags: math

Given a Player.X and Player.Y, and a Unit.X and Unit.Y, what is the formula to calculate the proper amount in radians to face the player towards, so that the player is facing directly towards the units x,y position..

Minimum radians is 0, maximum radains is ~6.3(360 degrees) for radians in the game I am modding in C++.

Example:

```
Player.x = -9000
Player.y = -150

Unit.x = -8950
Unit.y = -132
```

I am not great at math, so thank you in advance!

Comment: The C++ tag is for questions about C++ code, this question is about maths

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Sorry, did it by habbit, removed that.

Comment: If you have a math problem, you should consult [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hint: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2

Comment: Wouldn't you want the player to turn clockwise or counter-clockwise whichever is shorter? And, I am guessing you want the coordinates to be treated as vectors from the origin?

Comment: @jxh yes that's correct, clockwise or counter-clockwise whichever is shorter.

I am getting the coordinates of both the player and unit as a vector(x,y,z), but all I care about is the X and the Y.

So basically, turn left/right(shortest way) to Face unit, then I will continue checking that as I move the character forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `std::atan2` from `<cmath>`, then you might be able to do something like:

```
template <typename P, typename U>
double delta_theta(P p, U u) {
    auto delta = std::atan2(u.y, u.x) - std::atan2(p.y, p.x);
    if (delta > M_PI) return delta - 2*M_PI;
    if (delta < -M_PI) return return delta + 2*M_PI;
    return delta;
}
```

This generally returns positive if `u` is to the left (turn counter-clockwise) and negative if `u` is to the right (turn clockwise).